# Removing Custom Words From Text Variables in R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining, data-science, feature-extraction

I have Data set which looks like following:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),ADDRESS=c("EAST SS BLVD","SOUTH AA STREET","XX EAST ST","ZZ NORTH ROAD","WEST TR TRAIL"))

> dat
  ID         ADDRESS
1  1    EAST SS BLVD
2  2 SOUTH AA STREET
3  3      XX EAST ST
4  4   ZZ NORTH ROAD
5  5   WEST TR TRAIL
```

I want to remove all details in address not in list of words I want. I am using following code which is not proper and is not working.

```
 dat$FEATURE <- gsub("^[(BLVD)|(BOULEVARD)|(DRIVE)|(DR)|(ROAD)|(RD)|(PL)|(PLACE)
                |(SL)|(CIRCLE)|(CT)|(COURT)|(WY)|(WAY)|(ST)|(STREET)|(AVE)
                |(AVENUE)|(PKWY)|(WAY)|(PARKWAY)|(LN)|(LANE)|(HWY)|(HIGHWAY)
                |(TRAIL$)|(CIR$)]","",dat$ADDRESS)

> dat
  ID         ADDRESS        FEATURE
1  1    EAST SS BLVD    AST SS BLVD
2  2 SOUTH AA STREET OUTH AA STREET
3  3      XX EAST ST     XX EAST ST
4  4   ZZ NORTH ROAD  ZZ NORTH ROAD
5  5   WEST TR TRAIL   EST TR TRAIL
```

Output that I want is :

```
> dat1
  ID         ADDRESS FEATURE
1  1    EAST SS BLVD    BLVD
2  2 SOUTH AA STREET  STREET
3  3      XX EAST ST      ST
4  4   ZZ NORTH ROAD    ROAD
5  5   WEST TR TRAIL   TRAIL
```

I am not great regex any help is appreciated and any references for regex in R will be helpful.

Comment: You ruined the whole pattern by wrapping it with square brackets. `[(A)|(B)]` matches a single char, either `(`, `A`, `)`, `|` or `B`.

Comment: Square brackets `[]` create character sets that select one of any of the characters they contain. You don't need them at all here. Parentheses `()` create capturing groups, which in this case aren't really hurting anything but are unnecessary. The `^` and `$` anchors should also be removed, as they will probably cause your pattern to fail some intended matches.

Comment: `dat$FEATURE <- gsub("^BLVD|BOULEVARD|DRIVE|DR|ROAD|RD|PL|PLACE
                    |SL|CIRCLE|CT|COURT|WY|WAY|ST|STREET|AVE
                    |AVENUE|PKWY|WAY|PARKWAY|LN|LANE|HWY|HIGHWAY
                    |TRAIL$|CIR$","",dat$ADDRESS)` I had tried this first but it didnt work

Comment: Do you want to remove `BLVD` only at the start and `DRIVE` anywhere inside the string? It is a bit unclear what context you want to remove them in.

Comment: I want to remove any words apart from the words in regex, I want to only keep BLVD,DRIVE and all other words in regex

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/ttMrn5 I am not sure what is meant by `$` in `TRAIL$` and `CIR$` - is the dollar symbol literal here, or is it end of string? I also suggest matching those words as whole words. Also, what is the behavior when none of these words appear in the character vector?

Comment: it is end of string

Comment: Ok, so my demo still stands (word boundary is still there, at the end of the string, since the preceding char is a letter).

Comment: I cannot access the link you have given

Comment: If I understand, you want only the last word of each phrase in the `address`, variable, right?

Comment: not every time because sometimes these word also appeare in between the address, for e.g."S STREET ROUTE","COVE LANE SOUTH"

Comment: See http://rextester.com/QPEJO16593 - `gsub("(?xs).*\\b(BLVD|BOULEVARD|DR(?:IVE)?|R(?:OA)?D|PL(?:ACE)?
                |SL|CIRCLE|CT|COURT|WA?Y|ST(?:REET)?|AVE(?:NUE)?
                |PKWY|(PARK)?:WAY|LN|LANE|HWY|HIGHWAY
                |TRAIL$|CIR$)\\b.*","\\1",dat$ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)` (**do not copy the code from the comment** since SO adds garbage chars in them, or remove them after copy/paste)

Comment: can you please explain what is it doing

Comment: Please use `@`+username to notify of your comments.

Comment: See the answers below. Mine only keeps the last word in the string from you list. sln's keeps all words from your list in the string.

Comment: Yeah, once you can match the list, there are several ways to go. Remember, depending upon which answer you select dictates who to ask for help in the future when you need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?xs).*\b        # any 0+ chars, as many as possible, then word boundary
 (               # Group 1 start:
   BLVD|BOULEVARD|DR(?:IVE)?|R(?:OA)?D|PL(?:ACE)?      # Various words
   |SL|CIRCLE|CT|COURT|WA?Y|ST(?:REET)?|AVE(?:NUE)?    # you need to keep
   |PKWY|(PARK)?:WAY|LN|LANE|HWY|HIGHWAY               # here
   |TRAIL$|CIR$                                        # and here
 )               # Group 1 end
 \b              # Word boundary
 .*              # Rest of the string.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0OzBe/1)

Here, `(?x)` is a free spacing/comment/verbose modifier enabling formatting whitespace inside the pattern and comments inside. `(?s)` is a DOTALL modifier allowing `.` match any char including a newline (it is necessary as it is a PCRE pattern, pay attention to `perl=TRUE`).

The `"\\1"` replacement inserts the value in Group 1 back into the replaced string.

See the [R demo](http://rextester.com/QPEJO16593):

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),ADDRESS=c("EAST SS BLVD","SOUTH AA STREET","XX EAST ST","ZZ NORTH ROAD","WEST TR TRAIL"))
dat$FEATURE <- gsub("(?xs).*\\b(BLVD|BOULEVARD|DR(?:IVE)?|R(?:OA)?D|PL(?:ACE)?
                |SL|CIRCLE|CT|COURT|WA?Y|ST(?:REET)?|AVE(?:NUE)?
                |PKWY|(PARK)?:WAY|LN|LANE|HWY|HIGHWAY
                |TRAIL$|CIR$)\\b.*","\\1",dat$ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)
dat
```

Output:

```
  ID         ADDRESS FEATURE
1  1    EAST SS BLVD    BLVD
2  2 SOUTH AA STREET  STREET
3  3      XX EAST ST      ST
4  4   ZZ NORTH ROAD    ROAD
5  5   WEST TR TRAIL   TRAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
#R version 3.3.2 

dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),ADDRESS=c("EAST SS BLVD","SOUTH AA STREET","XX EAST ST","ZZ NORTH ROAD","WEST TR TRAIL"))
dat$FEATURE <- gsub("\\b(?!AVE(?:NUE)?|B(?:LV|OULEVAR)D|C(?:IR(?:CLE)?|OURT|T)|DR(?:IVE)?|H(?:IGHWA|W)Y|L(?:ANE|N)|P(?:ARKWAY|KWY|L(?:ACE)?)|R(?:|OA)D|S(?:L|T(?:REET)?)|TRAIL|W(?:AY|Y)).+?\\b","",dat$ADDRESS, perl=TRUE)
dat
```

http://rextester.com/GGYN78288

https://regex101.com/r/6RcXTi/1

---

I guess technically, this is more exact:

`"\\b(?!(?:AVE(?:NUE)?|B(?:LV|OULEVAR)D|C(?:IR(?:CLE)?|OURT|T)|DR(?:IVE)?|H(?:IGHWA|W)Y|L(?:ANE|N)|P(?:ARKWAY|KWY|L(?:ACE)?)|R(?:|OA)D|S(?:L|T(?:REET)?)|TRAIL|W(?:AY|Y))\\b).+?\\b"`

Comment: Sorry, just have to escape the word boundary `\b` -> `\\b` works fine now.